# Laravel relationships - 3-way table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models: `Basket`, `Product` and `Asset`.

A `Basket` can contain many `Asset`s, and one asset can appear in multiple `Basket`s.

A `Product` can have many `Asset`s, but an `Asset` can also be assigned to more than one `Product`.

The aim is to get `Asset`s into a `Basket` while still knowing which `Product` it was added from.

---

The table structure I envision having is this:

```
-------------------------------------
| basket_id | asset_id | product_id |
-------------------------------------
|         1 |        1 |          1 |
|         1 |        3 |          1 |
|         1 |       15 |          2 |
|         2 |       23 |          1 |
|         2 |        3 |          1 |
|         3 |       79 |          3 |
-------------------------------------
```

I also envision a model setup of something like this:

```
class Basket extends Eloquent {
    public function assets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Asset');
    }
}

class Product extends Eloquent {
    public function assets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Asset');
    }
}

class Asset extends Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }

    public function product() {
        // This should return the product from the product_id column
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about writing `Asset::product()` so that it returns the corresponding `Product`.

I'd like to call something like `Basket::find(1)->assets()->first()->product;` to get the product that the first asset was added to the basket from.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

Comment: If I understand you correctly the 'many' part of the relationship is actually a bit of a misnomer - there are constraints to the ways they work. Namely, given an `asset` and `product` combo, there will always be only one `product` that matches (regardless of the fact that, in general, `asset`s have and belong to `product`s and `basket`s, etc.) So, if that's the case we have something to work with (but can you confirm?). However, it's not going to be doable using normal Eloquent relationships as a given `asset` instance won't know which of the potentially-many `basket`s it was retrieved from.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Looks ideal I think - is there any way to easily consume that in Composer?

Comment: @alexrussell calling `Asset::find(1)->products` should return all `Product`s which the `Asset` is assigned to. Calling `Basket::assets()->first()->products` should do the same (note the plural `->products`. Calling `Basket::assets()->first()->product` should return the `Product` that the `Asset` was attach to the `Basket` with (note the singular `->product`).

Comment: Yeah exactly - but you have to realise that the `Asset`s returned from `$basket->assets()` don't actually know anything of the original `basket` whose `asset`s you asked for. It's this reason why you won't be able to use traditional Eloquent relationships to get what you want. If, in `Basket#assets()`, you use `->withPivot('product_id')` the `asset` will then have the original `product_id` from the pivot table. From there, you should be able to use that to get the (single) `product` for that asset. Does that make sense? But you still have to do that work manually I think.

Comment: But yeah, maybe just go with @JarekTkaczyk's solution. It seems to do what you want and the work's all done for you. You could submit a PR to Jarek to get a `composer.json` file in the repo (and submit to packagist). Alternatively, you might find [messing with the 'repositories'](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) section of your `composer.json` file can get it importing.

Comment: @Joe I didn't create a package of this, since it was just for playing purposes, no tests etc. but feel free to do so.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I've created a package and submitted a pull request. If you want to move your comment into an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Comment: @Joe done, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk no problem, it's a really nice trait. Makes something quite complicated exceedingly simple :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small piece that does what you need

https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot

and thanks to your PR a package on packagist:

https://packagist.org/packages/jarektkaczyk/eloquent-triple-pivot